When the scheduled task user tries to move a file from a symlink folder it can't find it
I did not set up the symlink, but my user can see the folder in my tree, and when I log on and trigger the scheduled task, it runs perfectly. We have a separate user which only run a scheduled task and when that runs the log always read no file found
